# c++ array shuffle not working

Tags: c++

I'm trying to shuffle array of strings and been getting the same array back after trying random_shuffle as below.

```
std::string arr[5] = {"a","b","c","d","e"};
random_shuffle(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr));
```

The shuffled array is in the same order in multiple execution of my program when I print it out.

Comment: [Works for me...](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f97c5955409dea16)

Comment: And [me](http://ideone.com/s4QDSj). Have you seeded the random number generator?

Comment: @MohitJain, me thinks it's seeded by `1`. And the question *is* about `std::random_shuffle`. Perhaps you meant `std::shuffle`?

Comment: @PaulR I followed the link and I don't see anything changing when I refresh the page.

Comment: @mashertmos Look at the output at the bottom of page.

Comment: @MohitJain, I'm getting the same output. `e d b c a`

Comment: @StoryTeller `std::shuffle` is the right way to produce random_shuffle IMO. But I mentioned `std::random_shuffle` to ensure there is no other local definition of random_shuffle in OP's environment as the MCVE is missing.

Comment: Mind that `std::random_shuffle` is being deprecated since C++14 and replaced by `std::shuffle`

Comment: Not sure now if OP means that (a) it doesn't work at all (array doesn't get shuffled) or (b) it works (array is shuffled) but he gets the same output array each time ? OP - please clarify your question.

Comment: I don't know what standard library implementation you are using, but keep in mind that the identity permutation is also an equally likely result. So I stand by what I said, if you don't like the permutation presented by the default seed, reseed `std::rand`.

Comment: @PaulR, not sure if it is a or b but the array is exactly in the same order after shuffling.

Comment: @mashertmos: you mean you get "a b c d e" as the output ? (BTW, OP, please get in the habit of providing a [mcve] when asking a question like this].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably forgot to seed the random generator. This should be called at least and preferably once. Preferably at the beginning of the program.

```
std::srand(std::time(0));
```

Comment: Language of question is ambiguous. You got it right.

Answer (score 1):

In [std::random_shuffle](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) the random number generator is implementation-defined, but the function `std::rand` is often used.

Unless you use `std::srand` to seed the RNG, you will get the same shuffled order everytime you run the program.

One possible fix is to use `std::srand` with `std::time` as suggested by kake_fisk in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36882613/c-array-shuffle-not-working/36882712#36882712).